# Highcharts Legend Not Showing Correctly after Resize

Tags: highcharts

At the moment I'm have a resizing issue with highcharts.

Initially the legend shows correctly, but when the user resizes the screen (to a smaller size) some of the legend items become invisible (although they are still there).

I've made a JS fiddle of the problem: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/peQr6/).

The following seems to be invisible (but there is no differance betweet the legend elements

```
<g class="highcharts-legend-item" zIndex="1" transform="translate(263,3)">
```

I can only recreate this on Firefox, (works correctly on IE, haven't tested Chrome).

Comment: can you share that link to us

Comment: @strikers I've fixed the link issue

Comment: @Binpower93 can't re-produce it on Chrome.

Comment: Which browser do you use?

Comment: I'm using Firefox to recreate this bug.

Comment: Reported: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2580